# How to put multiple if conditions dynamically in select statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table called categories as shown below.

```
mysql> select * from categories;
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| category_id | T1                 | T2              | T3                  | T4   | T5   | T6   | T7   | T8   |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|           1 | Popcorn            | Regular Pack    | NULL                | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           2 | Ice creams         | Cone            | KoolCool            | Choclate | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL 
|           3 | SoftDrinks         | Pepsi           | Tin                 | Large | Lemon | NULL | NULL | NULL | 
|           3 | SoftDrinks         | Coke            | Tin                 | Large | Apple | Mix | NULL | NULL |
```

I have got different categories of Items as mentioned inside T1 column (Popcorn, Ice Creams , SoftDrinks)
and each category can have up to T8 levels

With this below query i was supporting upto T3 Level

```
SELECT t1,
       IF( t3 IS NULL, CONCAT('(', category_id, ')'), GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t3,'(',category_id,')'))) AS consildated_Data
FROM categories
GROUP BY 1;
```

But Right now i need to support up to T8 levels

Could anybody please tell me how to achieve this

Say for example if PopCorn ends at T3 Level then i needed its T2 Level and with category_id in bracket .

```
+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| t1                                  | consildated_Data                                        |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Popcorn                             | Regular Pack(1)                                                |
| Soft Drinks                         | Pepsi,Tin,Large,Lemon(3)     
| Soft Drinks                         | Coke,Tin,Large,Apple,Mix(3)                                  |
  Ice creams                             Cone,KoolCool,Choclate(2) 
--------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cfe8/1

Comment: Thanks , I meant that Each Category can have upto T8 Levels of categories .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd return the specified resultset like this:

```
SELECT c.t1
     , CONCAT(
         TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM 
           CONCAT_WS(','
             ,IFNULL(c.t2,'')
             ,IFNULL(c.t3,'')
             ,IFNULL(c.t4,'')
             ,IFNULL(c.t5,'')
             ,IFNULL(c.t6,'')
             ,IFNULL(c.t7,'')
             ,IFNULL(c.t8,'')
           )
         )  
         ,'('
         ,c.category_id
         ,')'
       ) AS consolidated_data
  FROM categories c
```

Just concatenate together all the `t1` thru `t8` with comma separator; remove all the trailing commas from that, and tack on the category_id in parens.

Given the sample data, a `GROUP BY` clause isn't going to work, it would eliminate rows, and you'd only get back one row with category_id (3).

Comment: great , works exactly as needed , thank you so much .